# How do I begin with this integral? [Polar coordinates & line integrals]

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Calculate the line integral of the scalar field over the curve L:
>   $$
> \int_L(x+y)\,ds
> $$
>   with $L$ the right loop of $r^2=2\cos(2\theta)$

I've been going at it for over 3 hours now. With several people in a discord for math that were trying to help me but we can't seem to get the solution that should be 2sqrt(2).

Can someone help me get to the solution? :)

I tried the following:

x = r.cos(θ) and y = r.sin(θ) and my $ds= \sqrt{r²\:+\:r'²}d\theta 
 =\sqrt{\frac{2}{cos(2\theta)}} .d\theta$

from there I got my boundaries as θ = $\frac{\pi }{4}$ -> r = 0 and as θ = 0 -> r = $\sqrt{2}$

from here I got that the integral should be the following:

$\int _Lr\left(cos\theta +sin\theta \right)\:\cdot \sqrt{\frac{2}{cos\left(2\theta \right)}}\:.d\theta$

Now the issue is that I don't know what I have to fill in for the boudnaries of my integral. And even if this is correct what I'm doing.

Comment: Start by changing $x,y,dx$ to polar coordinates.

Comment: I did change them. keep in mind that it's ds, not dx.
x = r.cos(θ) and y = r.sin(θ) and my $ds=\sqrt{\frac{2}{cos(2\theta)}}$

edit: added to main issue

Comment: Then post your current advance.

Comment: My apologies :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the right loop we need $-\tfrac\pi4\leq\theta\leq\tfrac\pi4$ (note that many values of $\theta$ are impossible because they make $\cos(2\theta)<0$). So our curve is 
$$
s(\theta)=(\sqrt{2\cos (2\theta)}\,\cos\theta,\sqrt{2\cos(2\theta)}\,\sin\theta). 
$$
Then we need 
$$
\|s'(\theta)\|=\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt{\cos2\theta}}.
$$
Then, as $r=\sqrt{2\cos(2\theta)}$,
\begin{align}
\int_L(x+y)\,ds&=\int_{-\tfrac\pi4}^{\tfrac\pi4}\left(\sqrt{2\cos (2\theta)}\cos\theta+\sqrt{2\cos (2\theta)}\sin\theta\right)\,\left(\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt{\cos2\theta}}\right)\,d\theta\\ \ \\
&=2\int_{-\tfrac\pi4}^{\tfrac\pi4}(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)\,d\theta\\ \ \\
&=2\sqrt2.
\end{align}

Comment: You're an absolute legend, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathrm ds$ instead of $\mathrm dx$?

Comment: Yep! Thanks for noticing.